# Publicly-available real-time world-wide seismographic information?

Tags: geophysics, seismology

Is there a list of websites supplying real time seismographic information for around the world?

I could find for specific places. But I'm looking for a list so I can check for anywhere (providing, of course, they have it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IRIS Seismic Monitor](http://ds.iris.edu/seismon/) is one.

Comment: Add the [Geofon](http://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/eqinfo/seismon/globmon.php) as another one and you have a list of two.

Comment: For completeness - [this](http://rev.seis.sc.edu/stations.html?view=world) is the link for the actual near-real-time seismographs.

Comment: @makra Thanks. That can be helpful. Though I couldn't find seismograph-outputs there.

Comment: @ispiro more information on real-time access [here](http://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/waveform/seedlink.php)

Comment: @makra Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer.